# laravel 5.2 query scope with join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I want a list with all posts of users that are under the same subscription. So I have a subscription table, user table and post table.

Posts belongs to a user and users belong to a subscription.

I read on laravel.com that I can work with global query scopes.

SQL would be (I think):

```
SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN subscriptions ON users.subscription_id = subscriptions.id WHERE subscriptions.id = $subscription_id_of_user_that_is_logged_in
```

What do I have to put in my scope file?

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
  return $builder->where(????);
}
```

Second question: is this a good way to 'hide' posts from other users of a different subscription?

Comment: There is a package, doing exactly that for you: https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$builder
  ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->join('subscriptions', 'users.subscription_id', '=', 'subscriptions.id')
  ->where('subscriptions.id', Auth::user()->subscription_id);
```

It is a good way to hide posts from other subscriptions **as long as you ALWAYS use your Post model's methods to load posts**, as only then the global scope is applied. It won't be applied if you access data manually using **DB** facade.